# VSIXInstaller taking too long to install plugins on certain machines

Tags: visual-studio, vsix

I work on a product which gets installed as few extensions in the Visual Studio IDE. We found that on certain machines the VSIXInstaller is taking 4-5 minutes to install each of these extensions, while on some other machines it takes less than a minute. I am using VS 2022, but the issue has been reported on VS 2019 as well.

I collected the logs using the **Collect.exe** utility as described in this thread [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/vsix-extension-installation-hangs-while-installing/902546)

On investigating the logs, I can see that Visual C++ Redistributable is getting automatically installed and this is taking most part of the extension installation time. I suppose it is getting initiated by VSIXInstaller behind the scene. Suppose I install 5 extensions one after the other, the Redistributable also gets installed 5 times - once with every extension.

However on the machine where extension installation is taking less time, the Visual C++ Redistributable is not getting installed. So I suspect this to be reason for VSIXInstaller taking longer on certain machines.

But what I find strange is that Visual C++ Redistributable is already installed on that system. I cross checked the installed programs list and found the exact same Redistributable versions to be installed on both the machines.

Can someone please provide me some pointers as to why the Visual C++ Redistributable is getting installed with every extension behind the scene? Does this installation happen in some temporary location? And more importantly, what can I do to improve the extension installation time?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.